# Scan a large, INI-like file

Tags: c#, database, logging

I am trying to build sort of scanner, which crawls through a exported database and creates statistics on how many certain items were found. The export file is structured like this:

```
^
property1:  value1
property2:  value4
^
property1:  value5
property2:  value7
^
property3:  value2
property1:  value6
```

In this example I want to know in how many datasets does property1 have the value5?

^ is a byte sequence which marks the beginning of a new dataset. Problem is that the properties sometimes are not present in one dataset, or the order within the properties is different.

Currently I am looking through each dataset and loop through each line and check if the line starts with the wanted property, but I feel like that it could be done prettier and way more efficient.

```
public static Order getNextOrder(StreamReader sr){
            String myLine = "";
            String prop1 = "";


            while(!myLine.StartsWith("^") && myLine!=null){
                myLine = sr.ReadLine();
                if(myLine.StartsWith("prop1")){
                    prop1 = myLine.Split(':')[1].Trim();
                    continue;
                }

            }
            if(myLine==null)
                isFinished = true;

            var order = new Order(prop1);
            if(OrderFilter.accepted(order))
                return order;
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show what you're currently doing?  Do you have a *specific question*?

Comment: Specific question: Is there a more performant and or clean solution to this?

Comment: You haven't shown what your solution actually *is,* yet.  You discuss it, and showed sample data, but not how you're iterating through the data at all to offer any insight.

Comment: I added the snippet of the central part where I crawl one entry

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing looks pretty much fine so long as the file remains small and the number of questions you want to ask about the file is limited.

Basically parse the file into structured data and then query the data. In your case, read the file line by line and put them into `Order` objects which presumably go into an array and you can do some analysis on it. More complex solutions are just variations on this theme.

For example you could stream the data out into a database which is good at this kind of data analysis, such as Elastic Search. You could then do all kinds of interesting queries on the data without having to write any code other than the streaming parser.

If your file ever becomes so big that you can't process it in a reasonable time or load it all into memory at one time, or you need to give a non-programmer the ability to do arbitrary queries on the data, then you may need to put it into ES, but otherwise what you're doing looks fine.